# change fontshape for lewis dot in chemfig chemmacro

Tags: fonts, chemfig, chemmacros

I wish to draw a chemical reaction showing a radical chain reaction. I am using `chemfig` and `chemmacros` and `beamer`. `beamer` uses sans serif fonts which is good for display and less fussy.

When I write my structure as shown in the manual I end up with my reaction in `sans serif` but the radical and atom attached to it in `serif`, Initiation reaction {1} in example below.

I have used a phantom atom to get around this as shown in Propagation reation {2} in example below. The difference is between the Cl. radical on right hand side of {1} and Cl. radical on left hand side of {2}.

Although I have furnished a workaround, my question is:

Is there a way to have the lewis fontshape set to the global font shape? `\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}` did not change anything!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}
\begin{frame}
\begin{reactions}
 Cl-Cl ->[$\Delta$][$h\nu$] 2 "\Lewis{0.,Cl}"  \label{react:init}\\
R3H + Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" -> R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" + HCl \label{react:propagation}
\end{reactions}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: radical_reactions]

Comment: Just for sans serif fonts you could also every other document class, you would have to change to `\sffamily` with an explicit command then. And you should use a proper screenshot tool next time, where you can select an area first.

Comment: @Speravir Much appreciated. Will do the screenshot/crop image the next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chemfig`'s `\Lewis` uses `\printatom` (a `chemfig` macro) internally. You have to redefine it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}
\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{reactions}
  Cl-Cl &->[$\Delta$][$h\nu$] 2 "\Lewis{0.,Cl}"  \label{react:init}\\
  R3H + Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}"
    &->
  R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" + HCl \label{react:propagation}
\end{reactions}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can use `chemmacros`' own `\chlewis` if you have an up to date version of `chemmacros`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{reactions}
  Cl-Cl &->[$\Delta$][$h\nu$] 2 "\chlewis{0.}{Cl}"  \label{react:init}\\
  R3H + "\chlewis{0.}{Cl}"
    &->
  R3 "\chlewis{0.}{\vphantom{H}}" + HCl \label{react:propagation}
\end{reactions}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt solution. I had actually tried the `\chlewis{}{}` command but was getting a TeX overflow error. I have just realised I was using the wrong apostrophes `' '` instead of `"` around it... I also had used the redefiniton of `\printatom` in previous work, annoyed at myself for not thinking of this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leeser if I replace the `"` with `'` in the above example both work fine for me

Comment: sorry my mistake I used `` and I got TeX capacity overflow... using `"` or `'` works fine for me too.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `chlewis`